# PHPexcel How to show multiple sheets data in browser

Tags: php, html, excel-2007, phpexcel

```
<?php
require_once("PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");
require_once("PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php");
require_once("PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$inputFileName = 'R1.xlsx';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

This is my code its good to get excel **Sheet1** output from R1.xlsx file to browser. But R1.xlsx contain more than one sheets how to show them by link or vertically to show sheet2 and sheet3 data?
Thanks

PS.
I tried 
`$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(X);` by changing X value

Comment: You can try looping as as is shown as an example in this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740801/phpexcel-display-sheet2-in-html

Answer (score 1):

By default, the HTML Writer will only generate output for a single worksheet

You can specify which sheet to write by calling

```
$objWriter->setSheetIndex(2);
```

specifying the individual sheet that you want to output

But you can also tell it to generate an output for all sheets instead using

```
$objWriter->writeAllSheets();
```

before the save

Comment: thnaks buddy ,I want to generate link by fatching how many sheets are there in excel file.

Comment: You can identify how many sheets there are in the file by calling `$objPHPExcel->getSheetCount();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop, in each loop, output the content of each table.